# MongoDB _id Field Auto Generation?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to setup mongodb to test out its speed and am running into a issue with _id duplication.  I am not setting the is, I am letting mongodb do as I don't care.  I ahve the following php code:

```
<?php
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->selectDB("scrap_fighters");
$collection = $db->selectCollection('scores');

$data = array
(
  'user_id' => 1,
  'name' => 'John Doe',
  'score' => 120
);

$start = microtime(true);
for($x=0; $x < 1000; $x++)
{
  $data['unqiue'] = microtime();
  $result = $collection->insert($data, array('safe' => true));
}
?>
```

What does mongodb use to generate thier "unique" ids?  I even tried replacing unique with:

```
$data['unqiue'] = rand(1, 1000000);
```

To be 100% sure it was working but it still failed after the first write.  can I not enter records with the same data without specific generation a unique id myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses `_id` as primary key, and as such it has to be unique. Since you don't specify it, it will automatically generated. It consists of a microsecond timestamp and a hash based on the host, so even there are multiple hosts inserting simultaneously the probabily of collision is extremely low.

What is this `unique` field you are using? If you wanted it to be a primary key just don't set it.

About failing on duplicates: the only reason I can think of this happening is that you previously set up an index on this collection which requires some field (or combination of fields) to be unique. If not needed, remove it. If it's valid (eg: the user_id has to be unique) then insert unique records.

Comment: The unique field is _id and as my code shows, I am not setting the _id automatically which is why it is weird that the _id is being generated automatically with conflicting _id values.  This is also a brand new collection (not existing before the script is executed) so there are no other indexes on this collection.

Comment: drop collection, do a var_dump($data) after insert and check generated _id(s).

Comment: ANSWER: hahaha, I did not realize that the insert call added the _id to the array.  I added unset($data['_id']) to the end of it and it worked fine, thanks.